# Creating JButtons and addActionListener dynamically and pass JSON GetString

Tags: java, arrays, json, eclipse, swing

I am trying to populate actionListener of buttons automaticly but i get error at 
jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i) the generator() function return a JSONArray.

also i want to print  buttons[i] = new JButton("pfdfs"); as  buttons[i] = new JButton("i");

```
    JButton b1= null, b2= null, b3= null, b4= null,b5 = null,b6= null,b7= null,b8= null,b9= null,b0= null;
    JButton[] buttons = {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b0};
    JSONArray jArray = generator();
    //JSONObject jObject = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <buttons.length;i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton("pfdfs");
        btnPnl.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //JSONObject jObject = null;
                JSONObject jObject = null;
                    // jObject = null;
                    try {
                     jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Here I got the error!
jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i); error message Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

```
                    } catch (JSONException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    String name = null;
                    try {
                        name= jObject.getString("Name");
                    } catch (JSONException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
                    label2.setText(pyetja);
                    label2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
                    name.removeAll();
                    name.repaint();
                    name.add(label2);

                    Image image = null;
                    String photoID = null;
                    try {
                        fotoID = jObject.getString("photoID");
                    } catch (JSONException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    File image2 = new File("D:\\photoFolder\\IMAGE ("+photoID+").jpg");
                    try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(image2);
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JLabel image= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                    Photo.removeAll();
                    Photo.repaint();
                    Photo.add(image);


                    try {
                        String test= jObject.getString("test");
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                   }

    });
    }
```

Waiting for your response

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question - for example by providing the error message.

Comment: The error is here
 jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
error message
Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
Its my first question here :D

Comment: Please update your question - don't provide further details in comments.

Comment: And have you tried searching for the error message? This is a super common problem that was asked and answered here countless times before.

Comment: The point of question is the way to get from json array. 

 JSONObject jObject = null;
                    try {
                     jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i <buttons.length;i++) {
    final int k=i; //should create a final variable to get index. 
    buttons[i] = new JButton("pfdfs");
    btnPnl.add(buttons[i]);
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //JSONObject jObject = null;
            JSONObject jObject = null;
                // jObject = null;
                try {
                 jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(k);
```